# Video 'artifacting' in Chrome for 7 seconds, black video in Edge and IE for 7 seconds (Facebook, YouTube Gaming) - also on some GIFs

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, windows-10, video-playback

This is something I've noticed on Facebook mainly, and I believe it's caused by Windows 10 upgrade + latest AMD 15.7 drivers, because those are the only two things that have really been changed recently that could affect it.

**So, what is going on?**

**Chrome**

Well, on Chrome there is weird video artifacting; when video starts playing the colors seem to be shifted, some negative, whilst most of the video is black, and then video continues to play normal after 7 seconds.

**Edge**

Microsoft Edge is something I've never tried using, but now I did for testing purposes. The result is that videos, on Facebook at least, play completely black for 7 seconds and then continue playing normally, just like on Chrome. The main difference is that the video is completely black in the beginning, there is no strange artifacting.

**Internet Explorer**

IE has the same black screen like Edge happening for the same amount of time as the two above. However, on IE the video freezes on 7th second for maybe 2 seconds, and then continues to play normally after.

So, how do I play first 7 seconds normally then? Well, I have to start the video, then just drag the player line back to the beginning or restart the video then it plays normally.

I've also noticed this on **some GIFs on Imgur too**. Some GIFs in Chrome have that artifacting for 7 seconds if not viewed in full screen/separate tab in Chrome.

This also seems to be happening on **YouTube Gaming (YouTube's livestreaming service to compete with Twitch)**. The artifacting is there for about 7 seconds and then it goes away. I've noticed that artifacting sometimes just happens in the facecam of the user, whilst gameplay is intact for those 7 seconds of artifacting.

I have absolutely no idea what exactly is causing this or what the issue may be.

**OS:** Windows 10

**GPU:** R9 270X

Comment: If possible I'm interested in a solution that does not require disabling hardware acceleration (which is the only solution I've found so far)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

You can get rid of the problem by disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome `Settings -> advanced settings -> untick "use hardware acceleration when available"`.

It's not a perfect solution, however, because not having HW acceleration enabled often causes WebGL crashes for me in Chrome. But maybe that's specific to my setup, you might not have that problem.

I hope this helps.